# Angular 8 components showing below sidebar instead of being on the side

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular8, sidebar

I have a collapsible sidebar. On click of a link from the sidebar, I want to display the components next to the sidebar but they show below it.

My Component Code:

```
<app-topbar></app-topbar>
<div class="wrapper">
  <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</div>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/bn.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My Component's CSS:

```
.navbar{
    background-color: #1F85DE;
}
  .card{
    flex: auto;
  }
```

My Sidebar Component's HTML:

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="navbar-dark bg-#1F85DE"  style="background-color: #1F85DE;" [ngClass]="{'hidden': sideNavService.hideSideNav }">
    <hr>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home Page</a>
        <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link2</a>
        <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
        <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        <hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My Sidebars's CSS:

```
:host {
    background: #343a40;
    }

    #sidebar {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    }

    #sidebar.hidden {
      margin-left: -200px;
    }

    a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
      position: relative;
    }

    @media (max-width: 575px) {
      #sidebar {
          margin-left: -200px;
      }
      #sidebar.hidden {
          margin-left: 0;
      }
    }

    a, a:hover, a:focus {
      color: inherit;
    }

    #sidebar .sidebar-header {
      padding: 20px;
    }

    #sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    &:hover {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    }
    }

    hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 0;
    }







    .dropdown-submenu {
      position: relative;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%;
      margin-top: -6px;
      margin-left: -1px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
      -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
      border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu>a:after {
      display: block;
      content: " ";
      float: right;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-color: transparent;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
      border-left-color: #ccc;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-right: -10px;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
      border-left-color: #fff;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
      float: none;
    }

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
      left: -100%;
      margin-left: 10px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
      -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
      border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
```

The code is making my Sidebar appear on the left side but the component that I want to display is not occupying the empty save on the right of the sidebar instead, after the sidebar ends, its occupying the save there.

Comment: the container of both the sidebar and the main content should have a display flex.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-sidebar-container>
<ng-sidebar [opened]="opened" position="right" mode="push" autoCollapseWidth=100>
<img src="assets/myimage_compressed.jpg" class="rounded-circle" width=80 height=80/>
<ul class="menu">
<li> <a routerLink="/">Dash Board</a></li>
<li> <a routerLink="/post">Post</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</ng-sidebar>
<div ng-sidebar-content>
<!-- side page component ,Here i have used main component -->
<app-main></app-main>
</div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```